# Converting Trigger of SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am converting my Database from SQL Server to MySQL. I am facing issues regarding triggers.

Here is my SQL Server code

```
--IF A SALE IS DELETE WHICH WHICH INCLUDED AN ITEM FROM ORDER THEN ORDER SHOULD BE PENDING AS IT IS NOT DELIEVERED
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_ORDER_ON_SALE_DELETE
ON STOCKS
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT BARCODE FROM ORDER_ITEMS WHERE BARCODE= ALL(SELECT BARCODE FROM inserted))
BEGIN
UPDATE ORDERS 
SET ORDER_STATUS = 'PENDING' 
WHERE ORDER_ID =ALL (SELECT ORDER_ID 
                  FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                  WHERE BARCODE = ALL(SELECT BARCODE 
                                    FROM inserted));
                                    END
```

I have converted it to MySQL as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UPDATE_ORDER_ON_SALE_DELETE` AFTER UPDATE ON `stocks` FOR EACH ROW 

IF EXISTS (SELECT BARCODE FROM ORDER_ITEMS WHERE BARCODE = NEW.BARCODE)
BEGIN
    UPDATE ORDERS 
    SET ORDER_STATUS = 'PENDING' 
    WHERE ORDER_ID =ALL (SELECT ORDER_ID 
                      FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                      WHERE BARCODE =  NEW.BARCODE);
END
```

I am getting this Error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'BEGIN
> UPDATE ORDERS
> SET ORDER_STATUS = 'PENDING'
> WHERE ORDER_ID' at line 4

I tried different variations of code but I think I am getting error in IF EXISTS Statement

I also tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER `UPDATE_ORDER_ON_SALE_DELETE` AFTER UPDATE ON `stocks` FOR EACH ROW 

IF EXISTS (SELECT BARCODE FROM ORDER_ITEMS WHERE BARCODE = (SELECT BARCODE FROM NEW.BARCODE))
BEGIN
    UPDATE ORDERS 
    SET ORDER_STATUS = 'PENDING' 
    WHERE ORDER_ID =ALL (SELECT ORDER_ID 
                      FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                      WHERE BARCODE =  (SELECT BARCODE FROM NEW.BARCODE));
END
```

Comment: All code must be within BEGIN-END block, not out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax correction only:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `UPDATE_ORDER_ON_SALE_DELETE` 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON `stocks` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE ORDERS 
    SET ORDER_STATUS = 'PENDING' 
    WHERE ORDER_ID = ALL (SELECT ORDER_ID 
                          FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                          WHERE BARCODE = NEW.BARCODE)
      AND EXISTS (SELECT BARCODE 
                  FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                  WHERE BARCODE = NEW.BARCODE);
```

---

From the other side:

```sql
    WHERE ORDER_ID = ALL (SELECT ORDER_ID 
                          FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                          WHERE BARCODE = NEW.BARCODE)
```

checks that there exists only one `ORDER_ID` value for `NEW.BARCODE` barcode value in `ORDER_ITEMS` table. It is slightly strange...

Additionally - if such value exists then the row exists too (obviously), and the next condition

```sql
          EXISTS (SELECT BARCODE 
                  FROM ORDER_ITEMS 
                  WHERE BARCODE = NEW.BARCODE)
```

is excess.